# Cakephp configuration changes deploy

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I made some configuration changes in app.php locally.(cakephp 3)
For obvious reasons it is ignored by git.
So when I deploy to staging/production I need to edit the changes manually.
Is there a better/recommended way to apply these changes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you need two different configrations, one for the local development and one for the online production.

If so you have several solutions, this is one of them:

```
'Datasources' => [
    'default' => [
        // ...........
        'username' => (env('SERVER_NAME') == 'localhost' || empty(env('SERVER_NAME'))) ? 'root' : 'online_db_usename',
        'password' => (env('SERVER_NAME') == 'localhost' || empty(env('SERVER_NAME'))) ? 'blabla' : 'blablabla',
        'database' => 'db_name',
        // ...........
    ],
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm talking about adding a new feature, which requires  new variables, not as the database settings

Comment: anyway the conditional setting of the keys may make sense to you